# Tomcat war deploys to webapps/appname/appname

Tags: tomcat

We are deploying a Tomcat app (.war)

Once deployed it is only accessible in

http:\localhost\appname\appname

and not

http:\localhost\appname <---- This is what we prefer...

If we move the Webapp by coping the folder to the \tomcat\webapp\ we cannot start the app. It only seems to work if it is placed in a subfolder..

Is this an issue in the Web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Check your servlet mappings in your web.xml.

Here is an example :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/appname/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Could be replaced by :

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet-name could also be "faces". If you replace it by "*.jsf" make sur you access the application with the following URL : http:\localhost\appname\index.jsf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your war has a folder too much?
It should not contain a appname folder.
When TC explodes XX.war it creates an XX folder itself.